# How do I use update in firebase? I'm trying to make a document run auto without adding any values. What do I do?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How do I use update in firebase? I'm trying to make a document run auto without adding any values. What do I do?

```
await _tableFoodbook.doc().update({
                      "Bfavorite": myFoodbook.favorite,
                      "Bfoodname": recipe.foodname
                    });
```

Is it possible to omit the doc value?

```
await _tableFoodbook.doc("VXZB4eiQop1gpw7SE5La").update({
                      "Bfavorite": myFoodbook.favorite,
                      "Bfoodname": recipe.foodname
                    });
```

Comment: "I'm trying to make a document run auto without adding any values" What do you exactly mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: I would like to have the document id run automatically when querying data. Now I can only update it if the document id value is entered.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "run automatically". A Firestore Document id doesn't really "run". It is assigned either automatically or by you. And when you execute a Firestore query it can only return existing document, i.e. documents which have an ID. Therefore can you clarify you goal?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to omit the doc value?

Answer: No, as explained below.

I make the assumption that `_tableFoodbook` is a `CollectionReference`. By calling the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) method without any path the returned `DocumentReference` represents a Document that doesn’t exist.

Therefore, calling the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.D) method will generate an error as explained in the documentation of this method.

---

It is not clear to me what is your exact goal ("to make a document run auto without adding any values") but you may use the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) method with the merge method.

Comment: From sample code 2 I put the document id into the doc and it worked successfully. But I don't want this. I will fetch data automatically. From doc is there a way?

Comment: use the [set()][3] method with the merge method. Please recommend me some documents.

Comment: Link is corrected. Look also at the second part of this section: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document (under the sentence "If the document does exist, its contents will be overwritten with the newly provided data, unless you specify that the data should be merged into the existing document, as follows:"). But i'm not sure this will solve your problem, since I still don't understand it.